# Why does make4ht mathjax convert AMS gather environment to html code?

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax, make4ht

With the `mathjax` option, `make4ht` fails to render the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    E=mc^2\\
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{gather}
These equations are amazing.
\end{document}
```

I believe MathJax can handle the gather environment verbatim, but the `mathjax` option seems to try and fail to convert the equations into images.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is there a reason for not providing a doubl-backslash line-break directive after `E=mc^2`? (Aside: `e=mc^2` looks *just awful*, especially when placed close to `e^{i\pi} +1=0`.)

Comment: lol I agree!

The missing `\\` was a typo, corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default TeX4ht configurations turn `gather` environment into pictures. This configuration file should fix that:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{gather}{}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Result:

[image]

I've fixed this issue in TeX4ht sources, so this configuration should be unnecessary soon, if you use TL 2021.